# Finding a regression function

Tags: linear-regression

I began studying regression analysis today: A problem in my textbook asks me to find the estimated regression function for the following data.

[image]

For the previous problems, I've just used the formulas involving $\overline{X}$ and $\overline{Y}$. How can I do this one since the data isn't given completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only form an estimate based on the data you have.  Ignore the fact that there are $39$ data points you don't know and estimate based on the ones you do, using the same technique you have used before.  For comparison, I find $f(x)=11.04545+17.86363x$ from a spreadsheet

Comment: That's what I did, but the solutions manual has something different. Maybe the solution is the actual function with the missing 39 data points, but they don't indicate that at all.